# Spring Boot Integrating Testing: connection pool leaking

Tags: spring, integration-testing, c3p0

I have a spring boot application (1.5) that uses @Repos, @PersistenceContext and Connection Pooling (C3PO with mssql-jdb; 6.1.0.jre8) that connects to an Azure SQL Database. However, we are hitting connection errors when running our test suite. When doing netstat while running the integration tests, I'm seeing the ESTABLISHED connections expand without bound.  The number of connections hits ~250 connections and then I start seeing Connection Pool exceptions and everything eventually dies.

My question is what' s the proper way to handle this situation?  Is there a way to turn off connection pooling when doing integration testing or do I need to manually deactivate connection poolings at the end of a test?

Comment: you need to make sure your application reliably and promptly closes its Connections, in your integration tests as much as any other application.